# Annoying blue question mark "support"

Tags: blackboard

Today I opened my Blackboard (I'm a faculty member at un-named small American college). There's a new annoying floating blue question mark in the lower right corner. When you hover over it, it says "support", and when you click it, you are presented with a useless help menu.

The problem is that since it pops into and out of existence at just the wrong moment, you accidentally click it, rather than the "submit" button you were aiming for. I emailed my IT "Help" desk; they say it's a feature that they're testing.

[Here's a screenshot of the annoying blue question mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxTE3.png)

How do I get rid of this annoying blue support question mark? Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately this seems to be a question that is very specific to what is happening on this website. Stackoverflow is a place for programming and computer science related questions, so I think this might not be the right place for your question. You might want to go to https://help.blackboard.com/ for your question.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner than I posted, did I discover the solution. Digging into the html, I found that the annoying blue question mark is a Blackboard external tool provided by something called eesysoft.com. Using my privacy badger firefox addon, I just moved the little slider on the college.eesysoft.com field from green/allowed to red/blocked, and that eliminated the tracker from my browser. For good measure, I also edited /etc/hosts to block this tool at the local level. The same trick should apply to OSX, and I have no idea how to do this on Windows.

[Here is a citation to a page saying that the thing cannot be removed or blocked.](https://iteachu.uaf.edu/blackboard-support-question-mark/)

I'll leave this question intact, in case it helps others avoid this annoying, useless, blue question mark.